# Regex to split a string when there's nothing between two occurrences of the delimiter

Tags: java, regex, string

Suppose I want to split this string `a^b^c^d^e^^^f^g^h^^^` , I simply do `string.split("\\^")` which returns me an array of length 10 i.e `[a, b, c, d, e, , , f, g, h]` . However I want an array of length 13 which takes occurrences of the delimiter after `h` into consideration.

I can do something like this to achieve what I want

```
    string = string.replace("^", "^ ");
    String[] split = string.split("\\^");

    for(String x : split){
        System.out.println(x.trim());
    }
```

but this seems like an overburden. Is there a regex to do this?

Comment: You can simply `string.split("\\^+")`

Comment: @MarounMaroun: `string.split("\\^*")` gives me 16 and `string.split("\\^+")` gives me 8.

Comment: I didn't read your question carefully, sorry my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

```
String[] split = string.split("\\^", -1);
```

and it won't drop trailing separators.

---

If you really want to trim the last separator to get 12 values, you can do

```
String[] split = string.replaceAll("\\^$", "").split("\\^", -1);
```

or this will ensure you always have 12. It will either trim or expand the number of elements as required (adding `null` if expanding)

```
String[] split = Arrays.copyOf(string.split("\\^", -1), 12);
```

Comment: But the OP will not get 12, he will get 13  :) . The last `""` will also be considered

Comment: Okay my bad, I actually do want 13 as in some cases there maybe a char sequence after that last caret which is of interest. I'll edit the question accordingly.